# Problem with file by using fstream library and print on screen?

Tags: c++

I am trying to print the data located in the weapon.obj file, but it's not working.

> Compiler Error: error: no matching function for call to
>   'getline(std::ifstream&)'|

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream render_weapon_OBJ ("weapon.obj");
    render_weapon_OBJ << ("Weapon Names");
    render_weapon_OBJ.close();
    ifstream execute_weapon_OBJ ("weapon.obj");
    while (getline(execute_weapon_OBJ))
    {
        cout << execute_weapon_OBJ << '\n';
    }
    execute_weapon_OBJ.close();
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working"? Do you get compiler error? runtime error? unexpected output? What is in the file?

Comment: `getline(execute_weapon_OBJ)` is wrong. You must specify where to read the data.

Comment: Also you did not put any new line characters in the output file. You have only 1 line to read. You probably want to improve the example.

Comment: @drescherjm The line `Weapon Names` is put in the output file.

Comment: Note: `cout << execute_weapon_OBJ << '\n';` looks weird but valid syntax.

Comment: ...so? What did you expect `getline(execute_weapon_OBJ)` to do? You are trying to call a function that does not exist. Please include the error in the question

Comment: @Arnold-Baba Also please describe your desired behavior.

Comment: don't get me wrong, but asking on SO cannot replace reading a reference , eg [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Also it might seem obvious for you and we could guess, but you need to tell us what the code is supposed to do

Comment: @idclev463035818 it should print  ' Weapon Names ' on the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify where to read the data and use that for printing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> // add this to use std::string
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream render_weapon_OBJ ("weapon.obj");
    render_weapon_OBJ << ("Weapon Names");
    render_weapon_OBJ.close();
    ifstream execute_weapon_OBJ ("weapon.obj");
    string weapon; // add this for read buffer
    while (getline(execute_weapon_OBJ, weapon)) // add where to read
    {
        cout << weapon << '\n'; // print what was read instead of the stream
    }
    execute_weapon_OBJ.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this is the solution you are looking for
You need a variable to store the line read from the file and you need to print the variable not the variable used to initialize the file stream.
The error is in the while loop[The new code is below]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ofstream render_weapon_OBJ ("weapon.obj");
    render_weapon_OBJ << ("Weapon Names");
    render_weapon_OBJ.close();
    ifstream execute_weapon_OBJ ("weapon.obj");
    while(getline(execute_weapon_OBJ,line))
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
    execute_weapon_OBJ.close();
}
```